# Is there a way to retrieve all commits from the Gerrit REST API?

Tags: python, gerrit

According to the official [doc](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html) for the Gerrit API, you are supposed to access the commits by project if you have a specific commit id.

An example using `pygerrit`:

```
rest.get(r'/projects/psydev-lis/commits/dab837369ab0623f5869f500c199a23fd3249b82')
```

The problem is that I have been tasked with pulling all the commits ever made and uploading them into a database so that they can be tracked.  We do not have a database anywhere that contains all the commit ID's for me to query and iterate through.  Does anyone have experience with Gerrit that can help me figure out the best way to do a bulk load of all commit data?

Another issue I'm having is that I can only pull 500 changes at a time due to API limitations, and there is no way to track when you have seen all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about gerrit, but shouldn't you be able to do a normal git clone and get the commit information from there (git log)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used pygerrit myself but I have used a [Java equivalent version](https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-rest-java-client) that allows you to query 500 changes (commits) of a Gerrit project in this fashion:

```
GerritRestApi.changes().query(serverURL + "project:projectName+branch:master+status:merged").get();
```

If you add the tag &S=x where x is the offset of the number of commits you want to start looking at, you are able to iterate through the entire list of commits if you know the total number of commits in the project.
Example if you have 5000 commits in total in your Gerrit project:

```
int offset = 4500;
List<ChangeInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(offset >= 0){
    //Gets 500 commits from the offset and adds it to a list
    list.addAll(GerritRestApi.changes().query(serverURL + "project:projectName&S=" + offset).get());
    offset -= 500;
}
```

Remember though that this is the Java client implementation from the link above and it's not exactly syntax correct. But this might help you get the general idea of how to iterate through the commits.